# Show DOMAIN details

Tags: postgresql, domain

Showing the columns and constrains of a table in PostgreSQL is done with:

```
\d+ <table_name>
```

Which lists the columns, data types and modifiers for a table.

**How can I show the details and constraints of Posgresql [domain](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html)?**

Answer (score 11):

To view all domains in your database, run in `psql`

```
\dD[S+] [PATTERN]      list domains
```

You can see the list of all `psql` commands with `\?`.

`pg_constraint` stores check, primary key, unique, foreign key, and exclusion constraints on tables. Column constraints are not treated specially. Every column constraint is equivalent to some table constraint. Not-null constraints are represented in the `pg_attribute` catalog, not here.

Answer (score 0):

To get the entire list of domains in the database, you need to make an sql query:

```
select * from information_schema.domains
```

To get a list of domains that are used in table columns to check values, you need an sql query:

```
select * from information_schema.column_domain_usage
```

The view `information_schema.table_constraints` contains all the constraints for the database tables.

```
select * from information_schema.table_constraints
```

The view contains all columns that use table column constraints.

```
select * from information_schema.constraint_column_usage
```

The view `constraint_table_usage` identifies tables that are used by some constraint

```
select * from information_schema.constraint_table_usage
```